# PostSharp Licensing with DNX & Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, postsharp, dnx

I'm trying to use [PostSharp.Dnx](https://github.com/postsharp/PostSharp.Dnx) from GitHub in my DNX projects.

Upon build, I'm getting the following errors:

> Error PS0127
>
> License error. MyProject.dll uses non-licensed features (Portable
>   Class Library Support). Please visit >
>   http://www.postsharp.net/purchase to acquire a license of PostSharp.
>   The installed user license is: "..."

and

> Error PS0060
>
> The processing of module "MyProject.dll" was not successful.

I am using the PostSharp Express which should be compatible with these features.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you mark your aspects with `[Serializable]` attribute instead of `[PSerializable]`. P(ortable) Serializable feature requires "Portable Class Library Support" which is available only with a commercial license.